# Playstore upload rejected because of Platform Exception(sign_in_failed(f2.a: 10:, null, null))

Tags: android, flutter, exception, firebase-authentication, google-signin

1. Everything works fine in myapp.apk in release mode but when uploading on playstore the feedback from google was the error  *Platform Exception(sign_in_failed(f2.a: 10:, null, null))*
2. I have added all the necessary SHA1 and SHA256 in firebase.
3. generated SHA's from *./gradlew signigReport*
4. added  android>app>build.gradle as:

   ```
               defaultConfig {
                   // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
                   applicationId "com.abc"
                   minSdkVersion 19
                   targetSdkVersion 30
                   multiDexEnabled true
                   versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
                   versionName flutterVersionName
               }
           signingConfigs {
               release {
                   keyAlias keystoreProperties['keyAlias']
                   keyPassword keystoreProperties['keyPassword']
                   storeFile keystoreProperties['storeFile'] ? file(keystoreProperties['storeFile']) : null
                   storePassword keystoreProperties['storePassword']
               }
           }
           buildTypes {
               release {
                       signingConfig signingConfigs.release
                   }
               }
   ```
5. Checked out all other posts of people experiencing a similar issue (StackOverflow and GitHub) and attempted to do what worked for them but so far nothing has worked for me
6. Here is the error by playstore:
   [image: THIS IS THE SCREEN SHOT SENT BY PLAYSTORE]

Comment: Please add sha1 to the firebase console for this bundle id generated from release key store

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Go to your Google Play Console and Select your app.
2. From Side Navigation Go To -> Release -> App Integrity.
3. Copy SHA1 or SHA256 and Add it to your Firebase Console.